# Change Preview's default "Move to..." directory

Tags: macos, preview

Is there a way to set the default **Move to...** directory in Preview?

When a file is opened in **Preview** and **Move to...** is selected, the default directory is the directory that the file currently resides in. This directory selection is useless since I want to move the file *from* it. I'd like to set it to something else.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  I cannot find a Move To item in Preview's menu on Snow Leopard.  What version are you using?  (The closest I've got is "Save" and "Save As" ) Rmember that a 'rename' in unix is a move.  Eg.  mv foo.pdf bar.pdf renames foo to bar in the existing directory.